# ElementAPI : Excluding terms from search criteria

Tags: search, plugin-elementapi

I am trying to exclude terms in my search when using the element api. I have successfully managed to include terms and search them by fields in my entries. I would now like to be able to exclude different terms in those fields.

In this case 'recipeIngredients' is a matrix field.

Here is my criteria search so far :

```
//Get search query text
$searchQuery = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('searchQuery');
//Search in either title or ingredients
if ($searchQuery) $criteria['search'] = "title:'".$searchQuery."' OR recipeIngredients:'".$searchQuery."'";

//Get excluded ingredients query
$excludedQuery = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('xq');
if ($excludedQuery) {
    if (!isset($criteria['search'])) {
        $criteria['search'] = '';
    } else {
        $criteria['search'] = $criteria['search'].' AND ';
    }
    $criteria['search'] = $criteria['search']."recipeIngredients: not '".$excludedQuery."'";
}

//Get result count
$count = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam( 'count' );
$count = $count ? $count : 10;//Default to ten if no parameter

return [
    'elementType'     => Entry::class,
    'criteria'        => $criteria,
    'elementsPerPage' => $count,
    'transformer'     => function ( Entry $entry ) {
        return [
            'name'      => $entry->title,
            'url'        => $entry->url,
            //'json_url'    => UrlHelper::url( "recipe/{$entry->id}.json" ),
            'picture_url' => $entry->recipeImage->one()->getUrl(),
            'portions'   => (float)$entry->recipePortions,
            'time'       => [
                'total' => (float)$entry->recipeTotalTime
            ]
        ];
    },
];
```

I can't figure out if I should be trying to append the excluded terms to the search query, and my syntax is wrong, or if there is another criteria property available to exclude results.

Also, the [ElementQuery](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/element-queries.md) page mentionned in the [docs](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api#criteria) no longer exists. I assume, it's [this page](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-queries.html), but I'm not certain.

Comment: Did you read the docs about how to exclude search terms? https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html `- recipeIngredients:`

Comment: That's the correct page, Rhys... have updated the link.

Comment: @BradBell thanks for including the `parseParam` function and custom fields to the documentation. Now I can link to this page in about every third answer :-P

Comment: Thanks @RobinSchambach, that was the doc I was looking for. It wasn't mentioned in the ElementAPI docs, so I was a little lost to which search syntax I should be using.

A reference in the API docs to that page could be a nice addition. 

I've answered my question with the solution. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up changing my code to exclude search items.

```
//Get excluded ingredients query
$excludedQuery = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('xq');
if ($excludedQuery) {
    if (!isset($criteria['search'])) {
        $criteria['search'] = '';
    } else {
        $criteria['search'] = $criteria['search'].' ';
    }
    $criteria['search'] = $criteria['search']."-title:'".$excludedQuery ."' -recipeIngredients:'".$excludedQuery ."' ";
}
```